# Not able to start rails server , getting symbol not found in flat namespace

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-5, therubyracer

I am setting my `Ruby2.4` application on MacM1 with Ruby = 2.7, So I updated gems and other dependencies. Now, I am getting below error in starting server using `rails s`

```
require': dlopen(/Users/chakreshwarsharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.bundle, 0x0009):
symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN2v810ScriptData10PreCompileEPKci' - /Users/chakreshwarsharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.bundle (LoadError)
```

I tried to uninstall libv8 and reinstall libv8@3.15 using the below

```
1. Install home-brew for arch -arm64 &  old libv8 3.15 using the below
2. arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
3. vi ~/.zshrc
4. alias ibrew="arch -x86_64 brew"
5. export PATH="/usr/local/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
6. ibrew install v8@3.15
7. gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' -- --with-v8-dir=$(ibrew --prefix v8@3.15)
```

After this bundle install gets completed but I get the above error while staring rails server.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I have installed ruby2.4 and libraries using rosetta